# Access class defined in method in Java

Tags: java, reflection

In Java, is it possible to access class defined in method by some means (reflections or so)? And How?

For example, i want to create instance of InnerClass in example below:

```
class Example {
    public void outerMethod() {
        class InnerClass {
            double d = 0;
        }
    }

    public void testMethod() {
        outerMethod::InnerClass instance = new outerMethod::InnerClass();
    }
}
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: The only reason to define a class inside a method is to limit its scope to precisely that method.  If you want to access it from elsewhere, then define it at a higher scope.

Comment: I am currently developing tool that works with java code. So i need to know if tool automaticaly change location of inner class could it break the corectness of a code.

Comment: And as developer i should understand how it can be done. Thanks to user882813 i know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it is possible.
Practically this is a kind of a hack and you should avoid such practice in the production code.

Example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

class Example {

     public void outerMethod() {

        class InnerClass {

            private double d = 7.62;

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return String.format("[%s] d = %f", this.getClass().getName(), d);
            }

        }

    }

    public void testMethod() throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, InvocationTargetException {

        final Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("Example$1InnerClass");
        final Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(Example.class);
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        final Object instance = constructor.newInstance(this);

        System.out.println(instance);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, InvocationTargetException {
         Example instance = new Example();
         instance.testMethod();
    }

}
```

Here we first get `Class<?>` for our local class by their name. 
The local class name generation rules is a compiler implementation detail and may vary. AFAIK `javac` and `ECJ` use different approaches.
Then we get constructor of our class of interest via reflection. 
Since class does not define constructor explicitly compiler generate it automacically and this constructor is not public. So we use `getDeclaredConstructor()` method here.
Since this class is not static (local classes cannot be defined static) the first and the only parameter of constructor is outer class reference. `Example` in our case.
After that we creating instance of a class by calling `constructor.newInstance(this)`
`this` is passed as a parameter to the constructor. See note above about constructor parameters.

Finally, we print just created object implicitly invoking `InnerClass::toString()`

Comment: I tried represented example in Eclipse and it works (with little change respect to naming convention)

Comment: Sorry for delay, i didn't know about such function.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible.  Names declared inside a method can only be referenced inside the method itself.  Local classes (which your case is an example) are defined in section 14.3 of the Java 8 Language Specification.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-Block.